# Kubernetes Clusters and number of Pods

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am setting up a new project that will include a number of micro services (Spring Boot apps).  I plan to use Kubernetes/Docker and deployment to AWS.

there will be 5 separate applications (microservices) tat will talk to each other over a REST api.

**Question**

How many Clusters must I create?

Can I create just one Cluster with Nodes with multiples Pods (i.e. 5 Pods each Node)?  AWS will then auto scale the nodes in the cluster.

e.g.

```
+-------------+   +-------------+
|    Node 1   |   |    Node 2   |
+-------------+   +-------------+
|   Pod/App1  |   |   Pod/App1  |
|   Pod/App2  |   |   Pod/App2  |
|   Pod/App3  |   |   Pod/App3  |
|   Pod/App4  |   |   Pod/App4  |
|   Pod/App5  |   |   Pod/App5  |
+-------------+   +-------------+
```

Comment: are you using AWS EKS ? or managing yourself AWS EC2?

Comment: Why do you want to use Kubernetes for this use case? Can you explain which advantages you expect by using kubernetes? Kubernetes can be quite complex if you want to run it in production so also keep that in mind.

Comment: It may not be a concern for your particular project, but wanted to add one additional note: Technically it would be simpler to have a single cluster, however i think non-technical aspects should also be considered (in general), e.g. are these microservices managed by different teams/people and if so can/should they share resources like nodes, credentials, or even clusters, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use one AWS EKS that has one managed node group with two nodes to run your microservices. To create one, it is as simple as running a command [eksctl create cluster](https://eksctl.io/usage/creating-and-managing-clusters/). One thing to note is currently AWS EKS do not automatically scale node, you need to install [cluster autoscaler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/autoscaling.html) that will scale up/down the number of nodes for you.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create just one cluster yes, with at least one node. All your pods allocation will be managed automatically by Kubernetes.

If your apps need to talk directly to each other, you will even be able to directly call them with http://your_Service_name : the call will stay inside the cluster and private, thanks to this network mechanism offered by Kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

One AWS EKS is enough. But to run your services this cluster has to have one managed node group with two nodes.

Take a look at [this documentation](https://eksctl.io/introduction/). You can find here basic cluster creation with a different name:

```yaml
eksctl create cluster --name=cluster-1 --nodes=2
```

> **NOTE**:
> EKS supports versions `1.18`, `1.19`, `1.20` and `1.21` (default). With `eksctl` you can deploy any of the supported versions by passing `--version`.
>
> ```
> eksctl create cluster --version=1.18
> ```

If you want to see most options that can be specified during creating a cluster with `eksctl`, run following command:

```yaml
eksctl create cluster --help
```

At [this documentation](https://eksctl.io/usage/creating-and-managing-clusters/) one can find examples of config files.

---

About ***Autoscaling***, see [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/autoscaling.html).

> Amazon EKS supports two autoscaling products. The Kubernetes [Cluster Autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler) and the [Karpenter](https://karpenter.sh/) open source autoscaling project.

Before deploying the Cluster Autoscaler pay attention to **Prerequisites** you have to meet:

> - An existing Amazon EKS cluster – If you don’t have a cluster, see  [Creating an Amazon EKS cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-cluster.html).
> - An existing IAM OIDC provider for your cluster. To determine whether you have one or need to create one, see  [Create an IAM OIDC provider for your cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/enable-iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html).
> - Node groups with Auto Scaling groups tags. The Cluster Autoscaler requires the following tags on your Auto Scaling groups so that they can be auto-discovered.
>
>   - If you used  `eksctl`  to create your node groups, these tags are automatically applied.

---

See also:

- [Creating an Amazon EKS cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-cluster.html)
- [What is Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/what-is-amazon-ec2-auto-scaling.html)
- [How to Scale Your Amazon EKS Cluster: EC2, Managed Node Groups, and Fargate](https://www.pulumi.com/blog/aws-eks-managed-nodes-fargate/)